# Current sheet as PDF to Desired Google Drive Location

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been striving to make a code to save a specific sheet as pdf on a desired Drive location but its not working. I am no good in google sheet scripts but trying to learn.

`Sheet = Invoice`

`B5 = Name of PDF file`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
function myFunction() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZJmm4GHJUgtJRxuUMlgX3UA_yqSshhzKdqX2vr2kRw/edit#gid=730295684");
const nameFile = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice").getRange("B5").getValue().toString() +".pdf"
var pdf = docurl.getBlob().setName(name).getAs('application/pdf');
    var fid = 'abcdefghij1234567890';
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);
  folder.createFile(pdf);
}
```

I have tried to paste the ID and URL something is wrong with pasting ID's can you please answer the question in Code.

```
function myFunction() {
  //Sheet ID
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZJmm4FKuDgtJRxuUMlgX3UA_yqSshhzKdqX2vr2kRw/edit#gid=730374715");
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PaySlip");
  // Which ID would be paste here ?
const ssID = ss.getId(17ZJmm4FKuDgtJRxuUMlgX3UA_yqSshhzKdqX2vr2kRw);
  // Which ID would be paste here as well ?
const shID = sheet.getSheetId(1RTG7fwafO6Nro6mj4KZkZHjhyYpdTbAt).toString();
const nameFile = sheet.getRange("A2").getValue().toString() +".pdf";
const fid = 'abcdefghij1234567890';  
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);  
const requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
  // Which url would be paste here ?
const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=pdf&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;
const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
folder.createFile(result.getBlob()).setName(nameFile);   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Your current solution is not the proper way to create a pdf of a sheet. You need to use [getOAuthToken()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken) and [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params).
- Your goal is to generate a pdf based on the `Invoice` sheet, therefore you need to find the sheet id of the `Invoice` sheet and include it to the `url` element.

The main addition you need to make in your code is:

```
const requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=pdf&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;
const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);
```

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17ZJmm4GHJUgtJRxuUMlgX3UA_yqSshhzKdqX2vr2kRw/edit#gid=730295684");
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Invoice");
const ssID = ss.getId();
const shID = sheet.getSheetId().toString();
const nameFile = sheet.getRange("B5").getValue().toString() +".pdf";
const fid = 'abcdefghij1234567890';  
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(fid);  
const requestData = {"method": "GET", "headers":{"Authorization":"Bearer "+ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};  
const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ ssID + "/export?format=pdf&id="+ssID+"&gid="+shID;
const result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url , requestData);  
folder.createFile(result.getBlob()).setName(nameFile);   
}
```

Comment: @Learning glad it was helpful to you. Happy learning :)

Comment: Marios, can you please guide how to take pdf of selected area of sheet "invoice" ?