# Clone Googlsheet which has formulas/importranges

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to clone/copy a google sheet and locate it in a drive, The script i have at the moment is working for this element but the contents appear blank becuase of formulas/importranges

Please can you help with this. Current script is

```
function cloneGoogleSheet2() {
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxx"); 
   const file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").makeCopy("xxxxxxxxx", destFolder); 
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
     let rng = sh.getDataRange();
     rng.copyTo(rng, {contentsOnly:true});
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();             
  });
}
```

Reference to similar question below

[Copy a spreadsheet file to Google Drive and replace all the formulas with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66065003/copy-a-spreadsheet-file-to-google-drive-and-replace-all-the-formulas-with-values/66065758?noredirect=1#comment116808854_66065758)

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

Unfortunately:

- `importranges` can not be allowed programmatically. So you need to set get the values from the source spreadsheet and paste them to the newly created (target) spreadsheet.
- `copyTo` can not be used between two different spreadsheets, so you can use `getValues` and `setValues` instead.
- The logic is to iterate over the source sheets and for every sheet get values and copy them to the corresponding target sheets.

### Solution:

```
function cloneGoogleSheet2() {
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folder_id"); 
  const source_id = "spreadsheet_id_to_copy";
  const source_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source_id);
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(source_id).makeCopy("new_file", destFolder);
  const target_ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());
  const source_sheets = source_ss.getSheets();
  const target_sheets = target_ss.getSheets();
  source_sheets.forEach((sh,i)=>{
     let values = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
     target_sheets[i].getDataRange().setValues(values);
     SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  })
}
```

Comment: ok thank you for your explanation, as an alternative is it possible to create a copy as a pdf? as this will then show the contents?

Comment: @Alexasks I am afraid again this is a whole different question. Can you please search for relevant questions or post a new one :) sorry for the incovenience. Also consider accepting both questions regarding the clone spreadsheet.

Comment: @Alexasks btw this is an example of what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/64916043/11225291

Comment: @Alexasks [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)